# Google Talk Client for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, google

is there a Google Talk (gChat) client for iOS that:

- does not prevent messages showing up in other clients
- does not alter or send messages, add signatures or other spam?

Comment: Do you mean Google Talk? That's the only name I know it by.

Comment: Beejive GT maybe?

Comment: @Tyler (updated)

Comment: found this article comparing: http://mashable.com/2012/08/27/google-talk-iphone-apps/

Comment: beejive seems to prevent messages showing up in other clients (windows google talk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Hangouts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id643496868?mt=8) This is new version of Google Talk and official google product. You don't have to rely on third party products.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as why this is a good app to use? Pictures or more information would be appreciated.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes Hangouts will not prevent other clients from receiving.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes This is good because it is official google product, which means you do not have to rely on third party apps.

Comment: and finally hangouts is not as slow as a wet wick.

Answer (score 3):

[IMO messenger](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imo-messenger/id336435697?mt=8) seems to be a bit better, at letting the message get to other clients as well

Comment: My client of choice. +1 for IMO. I like it a lot.

Comment: Seems like IMO is always advertising itself with away and return messages. Been looking for an option to shut it off with no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vtok](http://www.vtokapp.com) where you can do chat, voice and video.

> - Free video and voice calls to all your Google contacts over Wi-Fi and 3G

Answer (score 0):

The app [Verbs](http://verbs.im) is a great chat client (think Adium for iOS). I use it with AIM and Google Talk and it works great.

Comment: Reviews say otherwise, but thanks for pointing this one out.